# List all image sizes still getting disabled sizes

Tags: filters, images

**First disabled/unset unused sizes :**

```
function remove_default_image_sizes($sizes) {
    unset($sizes['medium']);
    unset($sizes['large']);
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced','remove_default_image_sizes');
```

**Its work.**
Now I am trying to list all sizes : *(I posted shortcode, in real world im using code [something like this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_intermediate_image_sizes#Examples))*

```
foreach(get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $_size){
    echo $_size;
}
```

**Why Im still getting :**

```
thumbnail
medium
medium_large
large
```

`medium` and `large` should not be on list, since i disabled/unset them.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the `get_intermediate_image_sizes` function code solves your question:

```php
/**
 * Gets the available intermediate image sizes.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @global array $_wp_additional_image_sizes
 *
 * @return array Returns a filtered array of image size strings.
 */
function get_intermediate_image_sizes() {
  global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
  $image_sizes = array('thumbnail', 'medium', 'medium_large', 'large'); // Standard sizes
  if ( isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) && count( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) )
    $image_sizes = array_merge( $image_sizes, array_keys( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) );

  /**
   * Filter the list of intermediate image sizes.
   *
   * @since 2.5.0
   *
   * @param array $image_sizes An array of intermediate image sizes. Defaults
   *                           are 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'medium_large', 'large'.
   */
  return apply_filters( 'intermediate_image_sizes', $image_sizes );
}
```

As you can see, your applied filter isn't called in the function. Instead your filter is called in [wp_generate_attachment_metadata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata). So if you want to filter the sizes for the creation and the listing, you could add another filter to do so.

Comment: Thanks, But seems like its nothing changed

Comment: So you registered another filter like this: `add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes','remove_default_image_sizes');`, but still get the same output, right? Where do you register those filters?

Comment: Yeps, Right now I just use if else for filtering

Comment: Could you please provide the code?

Comment: Thanks for your help, So appreciated. But I have no time today. I will edit my question tomorrow :D Thanks so much